# How to show that the vertices of a convex hull are given by these specific subsets...

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces, polytopes

We work over $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $V$ be the corners of the unit cube $[0,1]^N$, or equivalently the set of vectors whose coordinates take values $0$ or $1$.

Let $d:\{0, \ldots, N\} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a function such that $nd(n)$ is concave, with maximum attained at $n_{\text{max}}$.

Define $S = \{d(\|v\|_1)v: v\in V\}$. Let $C$ be its convex hull. I want to show that if $v\in V$ and $\|v\|_1 > n_{\text{max}}$, $v$ is not an extreme point of $C$.

Comment: Previously posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185009/how-to-prove-that-the-vertices-of-a-convex-hull-are-only-defined-by-some-specifi where it got closed but did attract some comments.

Comment: Yes.. but someone told me that "the question is off-topic for MathOverflow. You should ask it instead on Math.StackExchange.Com"

Comment: Asking it here is fine BUT only if you link it to the MO post so people here can benefit from what was written there (and so people here won't waste your time by telling you things you were already told there).